# How can I copy building block text and formatting between different Word templates using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Platform**
Laptop computer
App: Word 2010
OS: Windows 2010
**Prerequistes**
In Word 2010, two test templates are used named tpOP.dotx and tpSRC.dotx, tpOP is the document template already open in Word in focus with tpSRC loaded as an Addin template.

**Code Wish**
I would like create a code snippet in Word VBA to implement the Word Building Block Autotext scenario as descibed here:

From the Word custom ribbon, I can do as follows:
Select: Insert > Quick Parts > Building Blocks Organiser.
Here I have two autotexts both named LOT with details as follows:

Name: LOT
Gallery: Autotext
Category: VE
Template: tpOP.dotx

Name: LOT
Gallery: Autotext
Category: VE
Template: tpSRC.dotx

I want to copy LOT from tpSRC to tpOP - To do this I can use the Word building Block editor. From the Modify Building Block dialog I can leave the Name, Gallery, Category, Description and Options the same, only changing the **Save in template** location which I change to tpOP.dotx.
Once this is done, I go back to the main story and then remove the tpSRC.dotx addin, without saving the changes and hey presto, the tpOP.dotx has been updated with my autotext changes copied from the tpSRC template. I hope there is enough information here.

I should point out that I am not a vba programmer but have a little self taught knowledge. I have researched many resources from Greg Maxey and MVP's etc. but nowhere is there information on how one can do the above in VB code.

The closest I have got to it so far is creating two building Block objects objBB1 and objBB2. objBB1 is attached to the tpOP template and objBB2 the tpSRC Addin template.
I found that I can use:

```
`objBB1 = objBB2
```

and this partly does what I want to do but it only copies the text of the LOT autotext item not the formatting.
Am I missing somethimg here or is it not possible?
Can anyone help with the code to do this.

**Reason for the code:**
I have a master template with autotexts and this forms the seed template for other boilerplate templates.
If the master template control elements contained in the autotext items require change (branding etc.), I can then migrate these to the other boilerplate templates. These templates are used to write various technical documents and a macro would suffice.

Many thanks.

Cudgel

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.organizercopy

Comment: Try `Set objBB1 = objBB2`. Without `Set` you copy just the default property which is `.Value`.

Comment: See http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/building_blocks_autotext.html and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/manipulation-of-autotext-wvba/dbfee11d-668b-4d35-9402-932b8bab34c4. The first one, Greg Maxey',s Add-In can copy building blocks from one template to another. Your branding could, perhaps, be in AutoText elements that are drawn into other AutoText using the AutoText field. In that way, you could simply change those elements and distribute your master as a global template.

Comment: Hi @Stringer, I noted your comment and on further investigation found this reference on the Microsoft VBA support site, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement. Under the Remarks general paragraph. It points out that the Set object function sets a pointer to the object not a copy and as such does not overwrite the value. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Hi @TimothyRylatt, I tried the Application.OrganizerCopy method but could not get it to work. It appeared to work with no error but gave not change. I came to the conclusion it might be deprecated and perhaps only works for Word 2003 as the Organierzer Autotext options was available then. Please ellaborate if you know different. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @CharlesKenyon, I previously read your articles on this approach and may have to go in that direction but as a novice, I thought there might be a vba method to simply do it as described. It is frustrating that one can do it manually through the quick parts buildingblock organizer but not recreate this in simple vba. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Greg Maxey did recreate it in his Organizer tool.